# files getting wrongly cached by the web server while using standard python file operations (Django)

Tags: python, django, file, caching

I have a Django app, which populates content from a text file, and populates them using the initial option in a standard form. The file gets updated on the server, but when the form gets refreshed, it picks up content from the a previously saved version, or the version before the Apache WebServer was reloaded.

This means that the file is getting cached, and the content is picked up from a wrong cache and not the new file.

Here is my code. How do I ensure that everytime, spamsource function picks up the content from the most recently saved file, instead of from a cache.

```
def spamsource():
   try:
    f= open('center_access', 'r')
    read=f.read()
    # some manipulation on read 
    f.close()
    return read
   except IOError:
    return "prono.nr"

class SpamForm(forms.Form):

    domains =forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs=attrs_dict),
                                label=_(u'Domains to be Banned'), initial= spamsource())
def function(request):
    # It writes the file center_access based on the changes in the textbox domains
```

Comment: How does Apache caching come into the picture? Python accesses filesystem. and python is invoked via apache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this. The problem was the presence of all the caching middleware in settings.py, which were being used to speed up another side of the web app.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is simply that all the parameters to fields are evaluated at form definition time. So, the initial value for `domains` is set to whatever the return value is from `spamsource()` at the time the form is defined, ie usually when the server is started.

One way of fixing this would be to override the form's `__init__` method and set the initial value for domains there:

```
class SpamForm(forms.Form):
    domains = ...

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SpamForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['domains'].initial = spamsource()
```

Alternatively, you could set the initial value when you instantiate the form in your view:

```
form = SpamForm(initial={'domains': spamsource()})
```

Comment: No. This Does not work. I still need to restart the Apache web server to get the results. There has to be someway to remove the file cache and load it again

Comment: Which one doesn't work? There's no such thing as caching of file operations in Django, so there's something going on that you're not telling us.

Comment: +1 Function definition getting a value from the method is an undebugable error. Everybody gets bitten once!